USB Communication between android App and PC Using C#
I am trying to interface an android app with a windows PC. The android tablet will act as the slave and the PC has the host. The PC will run a c# windows service, does any know what type of C# is needed to receive and send data via USB from/to android device.
I have tried this to get the list USB devices, not sure how read USB data:
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE PNPDeviceID LIKE '%USB%'");

// Get the collection of management objects
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject device in collection)
{
    string description = device.GetPropertyValue("Description")?.ToString() ?? "";
    string manufacturer = device.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer")?.ToString() ?? "";

}


The problem is that Android does not support USB device types other than the standard MTP PTP and ADB. For a custom communication you would need a protocol you can abuse upon, but without kernel modifications this doesn't seem to be possible. Als the USB programming on Android side is focused on Android running as USB host. Therefore the only workaround I see is enabling ADB and use adb port forwarding girl communicate via TCP.

There isn't enough information here about what you are doing, if anything, on the Android side, i.e. are you running an Android app you wrote, tablet is holding images to be retrieved by the PC side, trying to remote control the tablet, etc.

Hello Robert, I seem have made some progress using ADB and Socket on Android side and TcpListener class on the C# side.
